# New lines ignored when copying from vim

Tags: vim

My vim has developed a strange behavior.  I'm running vim 8.0 on WSL.

When I type code in vim, in vim it shows a `\n` character is present, but when I copy it to another program, the new line is lost and a very long blank line is inserted in its place.   After I save the file and reload it, the problem goes away.  I've tried changing the file type between dos and unix, in case something weird was going on `\r`, but that did not fix the problem.  When I paste it into a new program most of the time it actually looks fine, but things like the python interpreter take issue, as they see these as all one line.

I should note this is using the windows clip board, not vims. Vims copy and paste, puts the `\n`  in correctly, but I can't use that between programs.

right after edit

```
line1                                                                                                                                                       line2                                                                                                                                                       line3                                                                                                                                                       line4
```

after save

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

even on stack overlfow it  looks right when pasted, but as you can see above it is pasted without newlines.
[image]

Comment: When you say copy & paste... Are you copying it from Vim by selecting it with the mouse from your terminal? If so, that maybe explains it. Vim is free to draw the screen whichever way it wants, so sometimes it will actually use a bunch of spaces to erase the previous contents of the line and move to the next line. If you're copying from the terminal buffer, that's what you're going to get, since your terminal can't really tell that this was supposed to be two separate lines, to the terminal it looks like a long one that's wrapped...

Comment: @filbranden the copy is being done by the windows clipboard, but its not just grabbing a random buffer that is limited to what is shown on the screen.  I can confirm this because when I save the file and reload it, it copies correctly.  So it's not  a total miscommunication between vim and clipboard.